# Python: reshape array correctly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have the following function

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os.path

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

def predict_stock(stock_name, predict_days=30):
    start = dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime.now()

    stock = web.DataReader(stock_name, data_source="yahoo", start=start, end=end)
    stock = stock.filter(["Adj Close"])
    stock_data = stock.values

    # splits the stock into training data and test data
    training_len = math.ceil(len(stock) - predict_days)

    scale = MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_data = scale.fit_transform(stock_data)
    train_data = scaled_data[:training_len]

    # sets train values
    x_train = []
    y_train = []

    # test starts at day 60 and ends at 80 % of day end (test data)
    for i in range(predict_days, len(train_data)):
        x_train.append(train_data[i - predict_days:i])
        y_train.append(train_data[i:i+predict_days])
    x_train = np.array(x_train)
    y_train = np.array(y_train)
    #y_train.reshape(y_train, x_train.shape)

predict_stock('ALB', 30)
```

while x_train is of shape `(164, 30, 1)`, y_train is for some reason of shape `(164,)`, whereby the generation was the same.

How can I reshape y_train to (164,30,1)?

I tried the command:

```
 y_train.reshape(y_train, x_train.shape)
```

but this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

How can I reshape the array correctly?

Comment: it's totally normal that your y_train is (164) it contains the label only, your training x_train contains the features which are 30 features and 164 row.

Comment: why are you using x_train as argument?

Comment: My aim is to give y_train the same shape as x_train

Comment: OK, that's what the `x_train..shape` argument was for.  But why the whole `x_train`?  Did you check the `reshape` docs to see what kinds of arguments it expected?  Check the docs before running off to the web seeking help!

Comment: In reformatting the question I realized that you can't reshape `y_train` to match `x_train`.  You can reshape it to `(164,1)`, but you can't increase the total number of elements to match `x_train`.  But if `x_train` has 164 "samples" and 30 "features", `y_train` shouldn't have that 30 dimension.  It's just one value for each sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very basic flaw in your code is that you passed *y_train* as
the first parameter of *reshape* (it is a method of *y_train* array).

But spotting this is not enough.

If you want to rsehape *y_train* to the shape of *x_train*,
then *y_train* must have the **same number** of elements as *x_train*.
You can achieve it calling e.g. *np.repeat*:

```
np.repeat(y_train, x_train.shape[1])
```

i.e. "multily" occurrences of source elements, but so far the result
is still a *1D* array.

The second step is to reshape.

So the whole code can be:

```
result = np.repeat(y_train, x_train.shape[1]).reshape(x_train.shape)
```

I intentionally saved the result in another array, in order to keep
the source array for any comparison.

But consider also another approach, probably better matching the
computer learning methodology:

I suppose that it is enough to convert *y_train* to a **single column** shape.
So try:

```
result2 = np.expand_dims(y_train, 1)
```

This time the shape of the result is *(164, 1)*.